# Can I call methods with variables?

Tags: php, eval

Can I do the following in PHP?

```
$lstrClassName  = 'Class';
$lstrMethodName = 'function';
$laParameters   = array('foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2);

$this->$lstrClassName->$lstrMethodName($laParameters);
```

The solution I'm using now, is by calling the function with eval() like so:

```
eval('$this->'.$lstrClassName.'->'.$lstrMethodName.'($laParameters);');
```

I'm curious if there is a beter way to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually you're doing something wrong when you have to resort to this. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You really should try to reorganize your objects into different classes that have the same method name, rather than calling different methods on the same class. Then you can pass objects around, not method names.

Comment: Good job recognizing that `eval()` is not a good way to go. You should almost certainly *never* use string `eval()` unless you know exactly why you intend to use it, *and* you have ruled out all the better alternatives. But there are are too many better alternatives ... so you probably should not be using string `eval()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need eval to do that ... depending on your version

Examples

```
class Test {
    function hello() {
        echo "Hello ";
    }

    function world() {
        return new Foo ();
    }
}

class Foo {

    function world() {
        echo " world" ;
        return new Bar() ;
    }

    function baba() {

    }
}

class Bar {

    function world($name) {
        echo $name;
    }


}


$class = "Test";
$hello = "hello";
$world = "world";
$object = new $class ();
$object->$hello ();
$object->$world ()->$world ();
$object->$world ()->$world ()->$world(" baba ");
```

Output

```
Hello World baba
```

And if you are using PHP 5.4 you can  just call it directly without having to declare variables

You might also want to look at `call_user_func` http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: I updated the example for you to include 3 levels with an argument

Answer (score 4):

Did you try your code? The best way to find out if something will work is by trying it. If you do try it, you will find that yes, it does work (assuming that `$this` has a property called `Class` which is an instance of an object that defines a method called `function`).

There are also the two functions [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) which can be used for functions and for arrays rather than eval.
However the syntax is different from what you suggested, and the fact that I tend to avoid eval while possible, you can use it with:

To call it with objects, just do it like:

`$return=call_user_func_array(array($objInstance, "CLASSMETHOD"), $paramArray);`

Answer (score 0):

Untested but

```
this->$$lstrClassName->$$lstrMethodName($laParameters);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: Hmm, too many $ then .. obviously if you had $a="b" and $b="hello"; print $$a gives you "hello"...