# Can I use a variable value in $this in php

Tags: php

I was wondering if I can use a variable when using `$this` to call a function. It looks different than [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030355/can-i-call-methods-with-variables) as it doesn't require to use the class as a variable. Also the suggested answer here was not provided there.

Say sometimes `$x == 1` and sometimes `$x == 2`. Could you do:

```
if($x == 1)
 $var = 'name_1';

if($x == 2)
 $var = 'name_2';

$this->$var->a_function_here();
```

Instead of:

```
if($x = 1)
 $this->name_1->a_function_here();

if($x = 2)
 $this->name_2->a_function_here();
```

Comment: You can `$this->{$var}`

Comment: I could swear that I tried that (tried several things), but I just realised I overlooked something. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Would be useful to others who search for this question in this context. Thanks.

Comment: Is `if($x = ?)` pseudo? you realilze those are assignments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I call methods with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10030355/can-i-call-methods-with-variables)

Comment: You may have a look at [Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Just use it `$this->{$var}->your_function();`

**Edit:**
"PhD thesis" for those who want to understand more.

A "complete" answer to other users who may have the same question.

Sometimes it is better to use variables with function names to make the system more dynamic. You can do this with the mattresses.

Curly braces may also be used, to clearly delimit the property name. They are most useful when accessing values within a property that contains an array, when the property name is made of mulitple parts, or when the property name contains characters that are not otherwise valid

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: As @MKhalidJunaid gave the answer in the comment to the question first, I think it's fair to accept his answer if he posts it.

Comment: I see no problem in posting his response and you accept. What happened was only coincidence of him posting 25 seconds earlier.

I'm not here to earn points. I'm here to learn and help.